# What problems should I expect when adding a CentOS yum repository to RHEL?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm

I've added the [CentOS 6 Updates](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/) yum repository to my RHEL 6.4 machine. That's because RHEL doesn't ship with the php-snmp package - and the easiest one to find is on the CentOS site. Anyways, this appears to work okay in my environment - no problems I see.

My questions are if this is an acceptable practice - keeping the original RHEL yum repositories active and adding the CentOS to the mix? What problems, if any, should I look out for? Is there a way I can guarantee that the RHEL yum repositories are searched first (and CentOS last)?

Answer (score 1):

> What problems, if any, should I look out for?

From my point of view you should care about every `yum update` command.

As i know, CentOS had no access (at least till the union in [January](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2014-January/020100.html)) to the configuration of RHEL package building environment. CentOS maintainers can edit specfiles etc. Therefore CentOS packages (rebuilded from src.rpms) can provide differing dependencies, what can cause package collisions on your system.

Comment: *Extremely* unlikely, as CentOS strives for detailed binary compatibility with RHEL. In any case, using a repository like EPEL (which explicitly aims at complementing RHEL/CentOS) is less risky, in any case. But installing unofficial packages could go against the support guarantees...

Comment: I would be glad to know how did the CentOS team manage to uphold such a high compatibility level... I suggest that build machine configuration is a kind of trade secret for a Red Hat (because of Oracle of course). Ignorance of that leads to distinct differences of packages on the binary level: I worked on the project of creating RHEL-based distro and faced with many problems...

Comment: That is exactly why they normally struggled to keep up with new RHEL releases. But I don't have more details, the CentOS people were quite tight-lipped on their work (due to possible legal troubles, perhaps?)

Comment: I tend to agree with you.